# How can I avoid users can change the "Make revision" field?

Tags: nodes

My users can edit any content, but I really need to know what they did. I need revisions.
I tried the *Hide revision* module, but when the *Make revision* field is unchecked, the revision isn't created. They see that field, they uncheck it, and the revision isn't created.

How can I avoid they uncheck that field?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_revision_field

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Hide Revision field](https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_revision_field) module with this [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2020-07-28/hide_revision_checkbox-3001097-15.patch). See issue [[#3001097]](https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_revision_field/issues/3001097)